# How to configure nano to set tab to 4 spaces except for Makefiles?

Tags: nano

Is there a way to tell nano use 4 spaces insead of `TAB`s for every file **except for** Makefiles?

Comment: I believe this question is worthy of a second answer.  I seem to remember some version of nano somewhere that magically didn't break my Makefiles.  Is my memory faulty or is it possible to configure nano's conf files to treat Makefiles differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the following in my `.bashrc` file:

```
nano() {
  [[ -n $1 ]] && [[ `basename "$1"` =~ (Makefile|makefile|GNUmakefile|.+\.mk) ]] && command nano --tabsize 2 "$@" || command nano --tabstospaces --tabsize 4 "$@"
}
```

The names checked are taken from the [What Name to Give Your Makefile](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Makefile-Names) chapter of the GNU Make manual and are ordered according to their recommendations.

To keep things simple I only check the first argument.  In my case this is sufficient as any other configuration settings are set in `.nanorc` (**nb:** you will need to remove `set tabstospaces` from `.nanorc` if present).

I've only used this with BASH 4.x and do not yet have enough experience with the shell to know whether I've used anything incompatible with earlier versions.

**edit**

Also consider the `--ignorercfiles` command line flag as a way to improve upon this.